# Proc transpose having multiple ID values.

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

Hi I have a data as below and when I write the code it gives the error as below., 
I have tried different ways but not sure if I am doing it right.,

```
regid   Analysis    value
1378979 Samsjuklighet_L 0
1378979 andrainsatser_2_L   0
1378979 behandling_1_L  5
1378979 behandling_4_L  1
1378979 behandlingsinsatser_2a_L    6
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  1
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  2
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  3
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  4
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  5
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  6
1378979 boende_1_L  1
1378979 boende_2_L  1
1378979 droger_2xc_L    2
```

I wrote a code as follows

```
proc transpose data=X
out=Y;
var value;
by regid;
id Analysis;
run;
```

but it gives the error

```
ERROR: The ID value "behandlingsm_l_1_L" occurs twice in the same BY group.
ERROR: The ID value "behandlingsm_l_1_L" occurs twice in the same BY group.
ERROR: The ID value "behandlingsm_l_1_L" occurs twice in the same BY group.
ERROR: The ID value "behandlingsm_l_1_L" occurs twice in the same BY group.
ERROR: The ID value "behandlingsm_l_1_L" occurs twice in the same BY group.
```

I have taken a new way also.,

```
data X; 
set X  ;by  regid analysis value; 
if first.analysis then n = 0; 
n+1; 
run;

proc sort data = X; 
by  regid analysis value n; 
run;

proc transpose data=X out=temp1 (drop=n) let  ;
by regid;
var value;
id analysis;
run;
```

This gives a warning as the error above but deletes all the duplicates., but I want to have all the multiple values for the variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please could you post what you want the output dataset to look like for the input dataset you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

As sas log says you need unique values of the id varaible within each by group. This is not true becaues regid always has the same value. To have all duplicates you can create a by variables so that the values of `analysis` are unique.

```
data input;
infile datalines dlm=" ";
informat Analysis $25.;
input regid   Analysis  $  value;
datalines;
1378979 Samsjuklighet_L 0
1378979 andrainsatser_2_L   0
1378979 behandling_1_L  5
1378979 behandling_4_L  1
1378979 behandlingsinsatser_2a_L    6
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  1
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  2
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  3
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  4
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  5
1378979 behandlingsmål_1_L  6
1378979 boende_1_L  1
1378979 boende_2_L  1
1378979 droger_2xc_L    2
;
run;
proc sort data=input;
    by regid Analysis;
run;
data input;
    set input;
    retain conta;
    by regid Analysis;
    if first.Analysis then conta=0;
    conta+1;
run;
proc sort data=input;
    by regid conta;
run;
proc transpose data=input out=output(drop=_NAME_ conta);
    var value;
    by regid conta;
    id Analysis;
run;
```

Be carefull because if `analysis` is in any case longer than 32 character, it will give you an error